# SQL Server Date Conversion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

On applying the where condition :

```
WHERE DateFilled BETWEEN '02/01/2014' AND '02/28/2014'
```

My syntax is not detecting the values which are filled on `02/28/2014`.

If I write the syntax as

```
WHERE DateFilled >= '02/01/2014'
```

I am getting the output.

In the SQL Server table, `DateFilled` column has a value as follows.

```
2014-02-28 09:24:00.000
```

What could be the reason? Any date conversion is required. How to get `StartDate` and `EndDate` using `BETWEEN` condition?

Comment: If you have other code that uses `BETWEEN` on columns that have time components (hint: don't do that), I would strongly suggest going back and checking to make sure it's doing what you expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming that DateFilled has a data type of DateTime or other date type which includes a time portion.  When using DateTime values in T-SQL be aware that a time is always included and if not specified midnight is used by default.  See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878(v=sql.105).aspx#ConversionBetweenStringLiteralsandDateandTimeDataTypes
When the input string is "DATE only" then "the The TIME part defaults to 00:00:00."  In your case the string "02/28/2014" is converted to a datetime value of 2014-02-28 00:00:00.000.

Your query is interpreted as DateFilled between '02/01/2014 00:00:00 .000' and '02/28/2014 00:00:00.000' thus the record with a datetime of 2014-02-28 09:24:00.000 (which occurs after midnight on, is not found.

Your query may be re-written as

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM MyTable
WHERE DateFilled >= '02/01/2014'
   AND DateFilled < '03/01/2014';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
WHERE CAST(DateFilled AS DATE) BETWEEN '02/01/2014' AND '02/28/2014'
```

This casts the DATETIME variable into a DATE variable which does not contain time.  This does not work in SQL Server 2000 or 2005 though.  The DATE datatype was introduced in SQL Server 2008.